# How can I code in R the censored version of the EASI? That is, estimating the probit prior the specification of the EASI demand model.?

Tags: r, stata, file-conversion

This is not trivial. There is an easi package in R but it does not estimate the pdf/cdfs of the probit stage and then include them in the easi specification. This cascades down all the way to the construction of output and post-processing.

There is a Stata code but I don't have a license. Then I need to find out what is more cost-effective at this point: either spend time on conversion (without much of benchmark to compare) or simply buy the Stata license.

I tried ChatGpt for conversion of the Stata code to R, but the core program/function is about 130 lines, and it became unreliable and erratic. My code relies on the low-level Mata modules so there may not be direct mapping relative to R.

Here is a link to the stata code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TNujy341X0nUuP9ZEn-yAqqs7IrWHzID?usp=sharing

Comment: Is Mata meant to be Math?

Comment: Can you provide the Stata code and simulated data to run it? And a link to the easi package, as well as a reference publication for the method?

Comment: Mata refers to Stata's low-level prog language (https://www.stata.com/features/overview/introduction-to-mata/).

Comment: Download code from here:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TNujy341X0nUuP9ZEn-yAqqs7IrWHzID?usp=drive_link

Comment: I can't access your google drive link @MarioF; please edit your question to include the relevant code/details, or if the data is too large use e.g. pastebin.com (or similar) to share it with us

Comment: Please try again here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TNujy341X0nUuP9ZEn-yAqqs7IrWHzID?usp=sharing